# Insert a column to the dataframe paring values of the other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataset like this

```
BIN      NO1      NO2     NO3
1100      A       2.3      3
1200      A       3.4      5
1500      B       9.3      7
1300      B       8.0      1
1400      A       2.0      1
1600      B       3.3      3
```

I create a new column like this

```
A 1100
A 1200
A 1300
A 1400
B 1300
B 1500
B 1600
```

And my expected output is

```
BIN      NO1      NO2     NO3     CATEGORY
1100      A       2.3      3       A 1100
1200      A       3.4      5       A 1200
1500      B       9.3      7       B 1500
1300      B       8.0      1       B 1300
1400      A       2.0      1       A 1400
1600      B       3.3      3       B 1600
```

The new column (`CATEGORY`) needs to be paired(matched) with both column `BIN` and column `NO1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do

```
df['CATEGORY'] = df[['NO1','BIN']].astype(str).agg(' '.join, axis=1)
```